# Angular 4 sending HTTP request twice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hello and thanks in advance for the help. I just encounter a problem where my request to fetch a single event model is being sent twice.

Here are the functions I use to make get requests, also I'm hard coding the event arg. for testing only of course.

Api.service.ts

```
public get(path: string, params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
        `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
        { headers: this.setHeaders(), search: params })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .share()
        .catch( (error: any) => {
            if(error.status === 401){
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
            }
        });
}
```

Event.service.ts

```
getEvent(id: number)
{
    return this.apiService.get('/event/' + id);
}
```

EventComponent.ts

```
export class EventPageComponent implements OnInit
{
event: Event;

constructor(
    private eventServices: EventServices,
    private router: Router
){}

ngOnInit(){
    let id = 1;

    this.eventServices.getEvent(id).subscribe(
        event => {
            this.event = event;
            console.log(this.event);
        },
        err => console.log('Could not load Event with id: ' + id)
    );
}
```

}

Comment: do u have any async pipes?

Comment: How do you know its sending twice? Where are you seeing that? Wondering because I know Angular's built in Http service always sends an options request before your actual request which could appear to be 2 requests.

Comment: may you using same component twice?

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova no, I'm not using any pipes

Comment: @raykrow because I can see 4 requests using developer mode.

Comment: @0m3rF I dont think so

Comment: put a breakpoint and see who calls this method

Comment: Why are you calling `share`?